# How to open or run unknown file converted into byte[]

Tags: c#, .net, binary-data

I use to store document/file in byte[] in database, and I want user can view/run that file from my application.

Comment: I assume (from the brackets on byte[]) that this is for C#?

Comment: Are you storing that data yourself? if this is the case you should know what is the structure of the data and you can reconstruct that from binary...... But as you said its unknow file..its pretty impossible to reconstruct back unless u know what data it has..u cant do much than converting bytes to chars like notepad does...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to know the file extension for the file you're writing, so the OS can run the default program based on the extension. The code would be something like this:

```
  byte[] bytes = GetYourBytesFromDataBase();
  string extension = GetYourFileExtension(); //.doc for example
  string path = Path.GetTempFileName() + extension;
  try
  {
      using(BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(path, FileMode.Create)))
      {
         writer.Write(yourBytes);
      }

      // open it with default application based in the
      // file extension
      Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);
      p.Wait();
  }
  finally
  {
      //clean the tmp file
      File.Delete(path);
  }
```

Comment: Why not just `File.WriteAllBytes`? Also, that won't work since `GetTempFileName` will have an arbitrary extension.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to store the file extension in the database too. If you don't have the file extension the problem becomes very difficult as you cannot rely on the operating system to work out which program to launch to handle the file.

You can use the following pattern:

- Load data from database and save to file using the original file extension.
- [Start a new System.Diagnostics.Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca.aspx) that points to the saved file path.

As you have saved the file with the original file extension, the OS will look for a program that is registered for the extension to open the file.

Answer (score 0):

As chibacity and Daniel suggest, storing the file extension in the db, and agreed -- storing the file extension, or at least some indicator that tells you the file type, is a good idea.

*If* these files are of a format of your own creation then you might also want to store information about which *version* of the file format the data is stored in. During development file formats are prone to changing, and if you don't remember which version you used to store the data then you have a hard job recovering the information.

The same problems are faced in object persistence generally.